# How to query a mongo document using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB documents contain an array of objects and what is the best way to query those documents if I want to find and remove an object from an array with some specific value;

Here is an example of the document schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const LibrarySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  books: [
    {
      type: new mongoose.Schema({
        bookName: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        chapterReading: {
          type: Number,
          default: 1,
          required: true,
        },
      }),
    },
  ],
});

const Library = mongoose.model("Library", LibrarySchema);

exports.Library = Library;
```

If I want to find and remove a book with some bookName

Comment: To remove a specific book identified by its name you use an _update_ operation / method (the U of the CRUD).  Further, refer the MongoDB Manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Example :

```
Library.update({}, { $pull: { books: { bookName: "Yourbookname" } } })
```